# How can I automatically replace the ternary operator by if/else?

Tags: refactoring, ternary-operator

Sometimes I get some very ugly code which uses the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) too often. I would like to be able to detect such ternary operators:

```
statement ? if-block : else-block;
```

and replace them by

```
if (statement) {
    if-block
} else {
    else-block
}
```

If solution should work with Java.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the ternary a if-else block? They are pretty readable. In fact, I use Resharper for refactoring my code and it relentlessly provides me the option to replace if-else blocks by ternary operators.

Comment: By the way, a ternary operator is a type or class of operator. Specifically, it is any operator that acts on three discrete elements. Just like a binary operator is a type of operator that acts on two elements. The specific type of ternary operator that you refer to here is called a **conditional operator**.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thanks. Can you tell me some more ternary operators? @Pavanred: Do you really think something like the following is more readable than if-else? `return 1<t?(t<3?main(-79,-13,a.substring(main(-87,1-_,a.substring(main(-86,0,a.substring(1))))))
:1)*0+(t<_?main(t+1,_,a):3)*0+main(-94,-27+t,a)!=0?t==2?_<13?main(2,_+1,"%s %d %d\n"):9:16:0:
t<0?t<-72?main(_,t,strings):t<-50?_==a.charAt(0)?putchar(a.charAt(31)):
main(-65,_,a.substring(1)):main(((a.charAt(0)==’/’)?1:0)+t,_,a.substring(1)):
0<t?main(2,2,"%s"):a.charAt(0)==’/’?1:main(0,main(-61,a.charAt(0),values),a.substring(1));`

Comment: I don't think there are any more, but that's just an implementation detail. :-p

Comment: @moose in that case, I wouldn't try to replace the ternary operators with if-else (at least not initially), but first try to refactor the whole block of code. Once it looks better (which would also include using if-else, but might still have ternary operators), you can choose where to use if-else (usually for things involving more complex logic, such as calling functions), and where to use a ternary operator (usually for choosing between 2 or 3 values).

Comment: @moose: Well, that's obviously a contrived example written deliberately to be obfuscated.  Nothing is going to make that mess more readable.